# JavaScript - Show more info on click

Tags: javascript, dom, hide, show

How can I make the button to show only the ul that is inside its own div?
How Can I add unique ID's to each div, since I have a PHP code that outputs unknown amount of div's as result...

```js
 function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('table').firstElementChild;
  x.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Number</li>
    <li>Model</li> 
  </ul>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">More info</button>
</div>

<div id="table">
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Number</li>
    <li>Model</li> 
  </ul>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">More info</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't just say that you "were experimenting with" something, but actually post relevant code and ask a specific question about where you got stuck.

Comment: I accidentally posted first without code..My first ever post @ stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to pass `id` manually, simply pass [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the function to refer the current element inside the function. Then use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) to target the `ul`. Try the following:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
   var x = el.previousElementSibling;
   x.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Number</li>
    <li>Model</li> 
  </ul>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)">More info</button>
</div>

<div id="table">
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Number</li>
    <li>Model</li> 
  </ul>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)">More info</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to pass `this` explicitly

Answer (score 0):

pass the ul to your function:

```
onclick="myFunction(this.parentNode.children[0])"
```

Comment: Do you test this way?? No, Certainly NO. This passes the ul itself to your myFunction as a param!! function myFunction(theUL){theUL.style.display="block";}. ◎ simple and short and legible...

Answer (score 0):

1. `id` attributes must be unique, if you would like to use a common identifier you should use `class`es
2. The use of inline JavaScript and event attributes is discouraged, instead you should select the elements you wish to listen to using JavaScript, or use a delegated event listener as I have done below.

```js
const toggleInfo = ({ target, parent }) => {
    const hidden = +!!parent.firstElementChild.style.display;
    parent.firstElementChild.style.display = ['none', ''][+hidden];
    target.textContent = `${['More','Less'][+hidden]} info`;
}

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target, target: { parentNode: parent } }) => {
    if("BUTTON" === target.tagName && /table/.test(parent.className)) {
        toggleInfo({ target, parent });
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Number</li>
    <li>Model</li> 
  </ul>
  <button>More info</button>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Number</li>
    <li>Model</li> 
  </ul>
  <button>More info</button>
</div>
```